# RANSAC for finding equidistant points on a line

Tags: algorithm, ransac

There are similar titles that try to find an algorithm that has a bunch of equidistant points on them, but that is not what I want.

We know RANSAC finds inliers in a line. What I need is to find a line, but consider points only in a equidistant way inliers.

Now, the tricky thing is that, some of those points might be missing. If you look at below picture, you can see some of those points are there, but the model matched to it considers for the missing ones as the typical thing RANSAC would do. Now, adjacent points may be missing, every other, every two other, any situation may be missing, and so we want to find the model that includes the most number of points in it while the model considers only specific sections (equidistant points) as inlier.

Do you have an idea how to do this?

[image: sample]

Comment: Do you know the separation? If it is known, the two points selected for generating the line hypothesis can be constrained to be a multiple of the separation. Then, from one of these two points, a consensus can be computed considering only points whose distance is a multiple of the separation

Comment: No, we don't know the distance between adjacent points, although it is possible to put a limit to it. We can say there are supposed be n number of points that are separated for something in between 15 (meters) and 25 (meters), while the total points (inlier+outlier) are maybe minimum n to maximum 4n (Not all inliers exist).

All that can truly be said is that the matched model contains more points that would be equidistant from each other because most of inliers are going to be there, and the outliers are very unlikely to form a similar situation while very likely to form another line.

Comment: Maybe you can select two points, compute the line, and then count the inliers, supposing that the separation between the points in the line is the same of the two points selected

Comment: That's true but inefficient because we don't know how many other points are supposed to be in between. They could be adjacent, or 1-3,1-4... 1-n, so essentially there would be n models

I m trying to think that just like RANSAC helps with computing homography, there should be a mathematical model that can allow this.

Comment: *PART1* Can find a model based on more points (3 or n/2 whichever less) fit a model as n/2 gaurantee there are at least 2 adjacent p, however the chance of all being in one line is very low rendering RANSAC useless again. *PART2* Next, 2 points have to be used, ordinary RANSAC for line, all the points in that line found then **PART1** used because now these points are in one line, but this basically is a RANSAC inside a RANSAC.

Comment: Do you have sample data? Does the data contain non-colinear outliers?

Comment: I can generate some, but imagine random 2D numbers with potentially several lines in it, while only one would be structured in a way mentioned above. As a matter of fact if the line is too full of points, it is also an outlier because that is not the line we would want.